# pygame object not being deleted and square appearing only during collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision, del

I am trying to make a new rectangle appear when collided with an obstacle and the obstacle to be deleted but the del command doesn't work like in a tutorial i saw and the object only appears while the shape is colliding with the obstacle. How do i make the new rect appear permanently after the collision and not only while colliding and how do I fix the del command not working?

```py
#just the code for the collision   
if main.colliderect(obstacle):
    del obstacle
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color2, pygame.Rect(xr2, yr2, 30, 30))
```

```
#all of the code        
import pygame
import math
import random
import time
from random import randint
import sys
pygame.init()
fps = 30
fpsclock=pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

x = 275
y = 275
xr = randint(30,270)
yr = randint(30,270)
xr2 = randint(30,270)
yr2 = randint(30,270)
color = (255,0,0)
color2 = (0,0,255)

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene
    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed() #key imputs
    main = pygame.draw.rect(window, color, pygame.Rect(x,y,30,30))
    obstacle = pygame.draw.rect(window, color2,pygame.Rect(xr,yr,30,30))
    pygame.display.flip()
    if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 5
    if main.colliderect(obstacle):
        del obstacle
        pygame.draw.rect(window, color2, pygame.Rect(xr2, yr2, 30, 30))

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsclock.tick(fps)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Remember, in pygame or any similar gui, you are not writing and erase objects from a canvas, but each frame is a fresh canvas on which you have to redraw every object (including background) that you want to be on the screen.  So drawing things once will not persist.  @Rabbid76 has your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create the obstacle in each frame from the coordinates (`xr`, `yr`). I recommend to manage the obstacles in a list and remove the obstacle from the list.

Create a list of obstacles:

```py
obstacles = []
obstacles.append(pygame.Rect(xr,yr,30,30))
```

Use a `for`-loop to draw the obstacles:

```py
for obstacle in obstacles:
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color2, obstacle)
```

So the collision test in a `for`-loop and [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the obstacles from the list (see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating))

```py
for obstacle in obstacles[:]:
    if main.colliderect(obstacle):
        obstacles.remove(obstacle)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()
fps = 30
fpsclock=pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

x = 275
y = 275
xr = randint(30,270)
yr = randint(30,270)
xr2 = randint(30,270)
yr2 = randint(30,270)
color = (255,0,0)
color2 = (0,0,255)

obstacles = []
obstacles.append(pygame.Rect(xr,yr,30,30))

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene
    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed() #key imputs
    main = pygame.draw.rect(window, color, pygame.Rect(x,y,30,30))
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, color2, obstacle)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 5

    for obstacle in obstacles[:]:
        if main.colliderect(obstacle):
            obstacles.remove(obstacle)

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsclock.tick(fps)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```